# Google Fonts Flutter MissingPluginException Error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fonts

I face this error whenever I restart my app by exiting it (Note: I don't terminate the app, When I restart after terminating, it works fine.)

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationSupportDirectory on
channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
[        ] E/flutter (26338): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
[        ] E/flutter (26338): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (26338): #1      getApplicationSupportDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:101:24)
[        ] E/flutter (26338): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (26338): #2      _localPath (package:google_fonts/src/file_io_desktop_and_mobile.dart:28:21)
[        ] E/flutter (26338): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (26338): #3      _localFile (package:google_fonts/src/file_io_desktop_and_mobile.dart:33:16)
[        ] E/flutter (26338): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (26338): #4      saveFontToDeviceFileSystem (package:google_fonts/src/file_io_desktop_and_mobile.dart:7:16)
[        ] E/flutter (26338): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] E/flutter (26338):
```

Here is my `main.dart` file.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();
  final bgColor = Color(0xfff5f5f5);
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "App Name",
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        primaryColorDark: Color(0xff444444),
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
        appBarTheme:
            AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0),
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        primaryColorLight: Color(0xffffffff),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: bgColor, elevation: 0),
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Check out my answer for a similar case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573226/trying-to-place-call-directly-from-flutter-missingpluginexceptionno-implementa/67573992#67573992. Do consider giving it an upvote if it works. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TRYING TO PLACE CALL DIRECTLY FROM FLUTTER: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method callNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573226/trying-to-place-call-directly-from-flutter-missingpluginexceptionno-implementa)

Comment: I did all those steps mentioned but it didn't work. To solve the issue, I used local fonts. Thank you for your help :)