# Flutter file_selector plugin fails on iOS with MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Trying to use the `file_selector` Flutter Plugin across platforms.

I had no issues getting everything working on MacOS.

But, on iOS, I get: *Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method openFile on channel plugins.flutter.io/file_selector)*

```dart
class Scopes extends StatelessWidget {
  void openVCDFile() async {
    final typeGroup = XTypeGroup(label: 'VCD Files', extensions: ['vcd']);
    final file = await openFile(acceptedTypeGroups: [typeGroup]);
    print('${file?.path}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Color(0xFF52c7b8),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 40,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(onPressed: () => openVCDFile(), icon: Icon(Icons.import_contacts)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  file_selector: ^0.8.2
  file_selector_windows: ^0.0.2
  file_selector_macos: ^0.0.4
  file_selector_linux: ^0.0.2
```

It's a bit odd that this works with no issues on MacOS (had to add the entitlements), but fails on iOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi There. Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573226/trying-to-place-call-directly-from-flutter-missingpluginexceptionno-implementa/67573992#67573992

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I did remove the app, even did a `flutter clean` and same issue.

Comment: isn't this plugin is only compatible fro the ``web`` platform as mentioned on the plugin page?

Comment: As @OMiShah said, this plugin is `web` only platform so it doesn't have iOS support. Therefore no native methods are implemented & `missingpluginexception`

Comment: Thanks all - I get frustrated with myself when I miss obvious stuff like that.  I just assumed that since I had platform options for Mac/Windows/Linux, then the iOS/Android would just be there.  Apologies for missing that, and thanks again.

Comment: I came looking for exactly this. It seems that while it now works for desktop as well as web, it doesn't have an iOS/Android interface.

Did you find any solutions that will support everything in one? I'd rather not spin up two different plugins for either Desktop or Mobile.

Comment: I did not. I’m using two plugins.